# ¿Como extraer el fragmento de una cadena de texto que es variable?

Tags: sql, ssis

tengo una columna en SQL pero que tiene un formato parecido a JSON. Quisiera extraer unicamente el valor de ReportName : **""ReportName"":""Comercial - Direccion Sectores 2019""**. El problema es que el ReportName nunca se llama igual. Estoy trabajando con Integration Services y se me ocurre hacerlo con una columna derivada pero sinceramente no se que expresión o función utilizar.

Comment: Si nunca se llama igual... ¿Como sabes que columna es?

Comment: Esos datos los tengo dentro de una columna SQL de tipo NVARCHAR(4000). Y el ReportName siempre existe, lo que cambia es el contenido.

Comment: Y ese contenido, tiene algún delimitador por el que podamos saber donde acaba?

Comment: **El problema es que el ReportName nunca se llama igual**?